# How to get multiple CASE results to appear on within the same row on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, adventureworks

I'm looking for some help on an outcome I am trying to achieve from `AdventureWorks2012` using SQL Server 2014.

The outcome I am trying to achieve is the total sales per sales person for fiscal quarters.

I want the outcome to be 1 sales person per row which there total sales for Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4 (year July 2012 - June 2013)

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    pp.LastName, sp.BusinessEntityID AS SalesPersonID,
    SUM(CASE 
           WHEN MONTH(soh.OrderDate) BETWEEN 7 AND 9 THEN soh.SubTotal END) AS Q1,
    SUM(CASE
           WHEN MONTH(soh.OrderDate) BETWEEN 10 AND 12 THEN soh.SubTotal END) AS Q2,
    SUM(CASE
           WHEN MONTH(soh.OrderDate) BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN soh.SubTotal END) AS Q3,
    SUM(CASE
           WHEN MONTH(soh.OrderDate) BETWEEN 4 AND 6 THEN soh.SubTotal END) AS Q4
FROM 
    Sales.SalesPerson sp
INNER JOIN
    Person.Person pp ON sp.BusinessEntityID = pp.BusinessEntityID
INNER JOIN
    Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh ON sp.BusinessEntityID = soh.SalesPersonID
WHERE 
    soh.OrderDate BETWEEN '2012-07-01' AND '2013-06-30'
GROUP BY 
    sp.BusinessEntityID, pp.LastName, soh.OrderDate;
```

Current example of result;

```
LastName     SalesPersonID     Q1     Q2     Q3     Q4
---------------------------------------------------------
Alberts          283        2443.24   NULL  NULL   NULL
Alberts          283          NULL   NULL  NULL   32344.342
Alberts          283          NULL   34234  NULL   NULL
```

What I expect;

```
LastName     SalesPersonID     Q1     Q2     Q3     Q4
-----------------------------------------------------------
Alberts          283         2443.24   2324  1142   686858
Jones            287         2443.24   2324  1142   686858
Jimenez          299         2443.24   2324  1142   686858
```

Comment: Don't GROUP BY `OrderDate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix your `GROUP BY`:

```
GROUP BY sp.BusinessEntityID, pp.LastName;
```

Remove `soh.OrderDate`, because you do not want a separate row for each date.

Note that `SELECT DISTINCT` is almost never appropriate with `GROUP BY`, and certainly not for this query.